# IIS with multiple virtual directories on Azure VM Scale Sets

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

We are planning to migrate our internal legacy Applications to Azure IAAS.
We have tried to setup VM on Azure and host the same under IIS.
Need inputs regarding VM Scale Sets if we are planning to host all the virtual directories(Application's ) under VM Scale Set.

We tried the same to setup single application on VM Scale set.

Comment: We have an example running IIS on Scale Sets

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vmss-windows-webapp-dsc-autoscale/

As well as a tutorial 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell

Take a look at those and let me know if it helps. If not, can you elaborate more on your ask here?

Comment: We have multiple applications(Virtural Directories)  hosted under one website(test.appdev.com). currently we are using  4 VM's in production with one load balancer .  Need your inputs is it good idea to use the Scale set in this scenario considering some of applications are legacy ASP with COM component and also need to configure VM with initial COM setup is required

Comment: As you currently have it, are the 4 VMs identical? Or do they perform different functions?

Comment: yes all VM's are identical

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that. Based on your description of the application it seems like a great candidate to be hosted in scale sets. This will perform the same kind of function as you have no without the need to manually configure multiple VMs and load balance. I would start with creating a custom image so you have everything preconfigured on the VM. Then, deploy from that custom image into a scaleset. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Scale Set is a suitable for this application, in fact Scale Set is independent of IIS or COM altogether.

**Your challenge will not be Scale Set itself but application deployment strategy to the Scale Set.**

According to your message you tried a single VM host. Have you tried two VMs with a load balancer? Scale Set can have more than one instance so you need to test your application under load balanced environment. For example, if your application is using session state you will need to make sure that session state is persisted.